# Wordpress if current users is

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, user-roles

I have the following a function in my functions.php:

```
function admin_style()
{    global $user_ID; 
    if ( current_user_can( 'shop_manager') )
{  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', '/wp-content/themes/electa-child/admin.css');
}}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

I would like to add another user role but when I do  `if ( current_user_can( 'shop_manager', 'shop_assistant') )` I am getting an error.

How should I add another user role to be checked upon?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
   if( current_user_can('shop_manager') || current_user_can('shop_assistant') )
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Then mark this as the answer and if useful up vote too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get you current user role (translated) like this.

then you can play around with it.

```
 /**
 * Returns the translated role of the current user. 
 * No role, get false.
 *
 * @return string The translated name of the current role.
 **/
function get_current_user_role() {
    global $wp_roles;

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $current_user->roles;
    $role = array_shift( $roles );

    return isset( $wp_roles->role_names[ $role ] ) ? translate_user_role( $wp_roles->role_names[ $role ] ) : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Ashkars answer will work fine for your application - might be easier. but with this, you can use it anywhere.